# Wrong currency format

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I've done this...

```
[HttpGet("method")]
    public IEnumerable<object> GetStuff() =>
        repos.FetchStuff()
            .Select(c => new
            {
                val = string.Format("{0:C}", c.Rate)
            });
```

And it's formatted the currency as `¤8.00`.

Well, I wonder what currency that is?!

How do I make it show a £ symbol?

Comment: Currency symbols based on local culture. Can you check your culture ? 

check this : CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol
check this : globalization uiCulture in webConfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this one:

```
[HttpGet("method")]
public IEnumerable<object> GetStuff() =>
    repos.FetchStuff()
        .Select(c => new
        {
            val = c.Rate.ToString("c" , new CultureInfo("en-GB").NumberFormat)
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented above, you'll have to set `CultureInfo`:

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var total = 10.99;
        var numFormat = new CultureInfo("en-GB").NumberFormat;
        Console.WriteLine(total.ToString("c", numFormat));          
    }
}
```

Result: `£10.99`